# Compare 2 times in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns in `xyz` table, as `start_time` and `end_time` in 2 different tables.

```
table 1 - start_time & end_time
table 2 - avg_start_time & avg_end_time.
```

I need to check whether `start_time`(`table1`) is greater than `avg_start_time`. some how I am not getting output, however I am getting the expected answer if I do the less than instead of greater than,

```
to_char(start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') < to_char(avg_start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') -- no output

to_char(start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') > to_char(avg_start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') -- 
table values output - 
-- 20:11:04(start_time) 20:05:00(avg_start_time)
```

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: If the tables are small, can you show us the data? And the sql that you're running?

Comment: select * from table1 a, table2 b where to_char(a.start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') < to_char(b.start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') ;

Comment: getting output - when i hit less than instead of greater than

Comment: select * from table1 a, table2 b where to_char(a.start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') > to_char(b.start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') ;

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result, including your tabe structure.

Answer (score 0):

can you try MSSQL

```
CAST(start_timeas as time) < cast(avg_start_time as time)?
```

update answer

Oracle:
my idea is create new timestamps from date now and time from objects and that values compared

```
to_timestamp((to_char(trunc(sysdate),'dd.MM.yyyy') || ' ' || to_Char(start_timeas, 'hh24:mi:ss')),'dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') < to_timestamp((to_char(trunc(sysdate),'dd.MM.yyyy') || ' ' || to_Char(avg_start_time, 'hh24:mi:ss')),'dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: If the dates are columns of DATE type, why not simply compare them? why do you need all this type conversions?

Comment: because we need compare only time, not date. in this case we set date (same date) today and time who we want compare